# JSONB Column Type

Tags: jhipster, jsonb

I was reading through the JHipster "Creating an entity", and did not see any Field Type related to JSONB.  Does JHipster have any examples of jsonb field types?

Comment: No it's not supported. You have to code it by yourself using https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types